# Name of an operation that joins words into phrases

Tags: formal-languages, binary-operations

Is there a name for an operation that joins words into phrases? Like, given 'gray' and 'cat' the operation *(gray, cat) = 'gray cat'. It's not concatenation, because I'm not seeking 'graycat', but 'gray cat'.

Comment: Delimited concatenation is probably closer to what you want.  "Delimiter" is a standard term in software design.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks!

Comment: I thought the usual approach to formalizing phrases of multiple words was to treat the words as atoms, so the operation of stringing them together _is_ concatenation. It's just that "concatenation" must not turn two atoms into one. The space is simply a notational device for indicating this.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such operation name. However, I would suggest "interstitial concatenation" if you like, since we are adding the "interstice" blank space between the words. Alternatively, "lacunar concatenation" would sound nice.

Comment: I like that name!

Comment: Thank you. It is just an opinion.